# Upgrade of package from 5.x to 11

Tags: packages, upgrade

I'm new to mathematica and I'm trying to upgrade [TamarA](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/839/) package, because it shows wierd things. To be more precise in case of formulas which should result into fraction of some elements the resulting fraction contains additional label TamarA` (yes with apostrophe as it was a context/namespace name) and the result is hence wrong.

Example:
This notebook:

```
Needs["TamarA`"]
N1 = lg[vb[k1], 1 - gm[5], v[k2]]*lg[ub[p1], 1 - gm[5], u[p2]]
N1s = lg[vb[k1], gm[up[\[Alpha], \[Beta]]], 1 - gm[5], v[k2]]*
      lg[ub[p1], sl[a], gm[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], sl[b], 1 - gm[5], 
      u[p2]]
N2s = lg[vb[k1], gm[up[\[Alpha], \[Beta]]], 1 - gm[5], v[k2]]*
      lg[ub[p1], gm[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], 1 - gm[5], u[p2]]
N1*cj[N1s]
% // ReleaseHold
% // Expand // Together
% // Expand
R1 = %
```

evaluates in older version of mathematica into something starting like this:

[image]

but in mathematica 11 I see some additional output (looks like a context name) (i underlined the problematic part):

[image]
Could anybody help me with this? I feel I'm missing something trivial here. Thanks.

I'm using Mathematica 11.3.0, student version, under 64bit Ubuntu Linux 16.04.

Comment: The TamarA package exports a bunch of lower case public symbols, e.g., `g, m, sc, sg, sl, tr, up, dn, vec, v4, v3, d4, eps, gm, D4IndexQ, IndexQ, ToBasis, lg, OpenLg, delta, sc3, trs, vec3, s, ep3, D3IndexQ, d3, ToD3, ToD4, ToSBasis, ls, OpenLs, cj, u, ub, v, vb, VecNameQ,ExVecNameQ`. This means that there is a shadowing problem between the TamarA` public symbols and your Global` symbols, which is why the TamarA` context gets added.

Comment: @Carl, that was my first guess as well, but I think it's actually something to do with how some `MakeBoxes` rules are defined in the package.

Comment: I’d imagine TamarA is effectively rendered obsolete by the more established FeynCalc, or the more recent Package-X.  I could be wrong though.  It may be worth looking into them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `` TamarA` `` goes away if I edit the `MakeBoxes` rules in the package from things like

```
m/: MakeBoxes[m[x_?Sym3Q],StandardForm]:=
 TagBox[
 SubscriptBox[m,MakeBoxes[x,StandardForm]],mass,Editable->False];
```

to

```
m/: MakeBoxes[m[x_?Sym3Q],StandardForm]:=
 TagBox[
 SubscriptBox[MakeBoxes[m, StandardForm],
    MakeBoxes[x,StandardForm]],mass,Editable->False];
```

It's possible the corresponding `MakeExpressions` rules also need updated, but I haven't looked at them.